# Ruby/Grape required parameters on a certain condition

Tags: ruby, api, rack, ruby-grape, grape-api

For one of my methods the following isn't working. I pretty much copied everything straight out of the official documentation:

```
params do
requires :authenticationType, type: Array[String], values: ['LOCAL', 'AD']
given authenticationType: ->(val) { val == 'LOCAL' } do
  requires :admin, type: String, allow_blank: false, regexp: /^[\w\.\@-]{1,64}$/
  requires :password, type: String, allow_blank: false, regexp: /^[\w\.\@-]{1,64}$/
end
end
```

It is giving an error on the "given" line. Anyone know what is wrong. My goal: ONLY if 'authenticationType' == 'LOCAL' should the user provide 'admin' and 'password'

error:

> [ 2017-03-03 00:39:18.4848 14970/7f5d0603f700
>   age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for
>   application /vagrant/masterapi: An error occurred while starting up
>   the preloader.   Error ID: 0bd79149   Error details saved to:
>   /tmp/passenger-error-3OYsdJ.html   Message from application:
>   Grape::Exceptions::UnknownParameter
>   (Grape::Exceptions::UnknownParameter)
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.16.2/lib/grape/dsl/parameters.rb:170:in
>   `block in given'
>
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.16.2/lib/grape/dsl/parameters.rb:169:in`
>   each'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/grape-0.16.2/lib/grape/dsl/parameters.rb:169:in
>   `given'   /vagrant/masterapi/controllers/papi_controller.rb:93:in`
>   block in '

Comment: you should show the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'given' accepts proc only since grape version 0.17, implemented in merge request (MR) [1443](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/pull/1443). So you should either update, or if that's not feasible, try back-porting this MR to 0.16.2.

[Here's](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/tree/v0.16.2) the README for your version.

Also, in your example, `authenticationType` param is of type `Array[String]`, so (at least in grape 0.17), the proc will receive a `Hashie::Array`.

This means:

`->(val) { val == 'LOCAL' }`

should be

`->(val) { val.first == 'LOCAL' }`